# Polygon parcel division in python

Tags: python, polygon

Is there an open source tool or module in python that does parcel division of polygons like in [ArcEditor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003wp000000.htm)?

Comment: this link may help you http://lists.gispython.org/pipermail/community/2012-August/003135.html

Comment: It's Dead, Jim.

Comment: with [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) at [Spliting a polygon into two polygons with the same area](http://community-gispython-org-community-projects.955323.n3.nabble.com/Community-Spliting-a-polygon-into-two-polygons-with-the-same-area-td4024026.html#a4024033)